# Como mostrar 2 linhas no ListBox

Tags: vba, listbox

É uma dúvida simples porém pesquisei e não consegui achar algo específico para o meu caso.
O código abaixo corresponde a pesquisa de dados em uma tabela, porém quando há mais de 1 valor correspondente, ele substitui o último valor encontrado. O que eu gostaria é que ele adicione uma linha conforme o exemplo abaixo:

**O exemplo não tem relação com o código

Tabela

**AAA 111 222 333**

**AAA 111 555 777**

Procurar: **AAA**

Resultado atualmente:

**AAA 111 555 777**(substituído por AAA 222 333)

O que eu gostaria:

**AAA 111 222 333**

**AAA 111 555 777**

```
Private Sub Pesquisar_Click()
    Dim nApol As String
    Dim nApolBanco As String
    Dim nlin As Long
    Dim Linha As Range


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If Len(Me.TextBox1.Value) > 3 Then

        nApol = TextBox1.Value + TextBox2.Value + TextBox3.Value

        For nlin = 2 To Sheets("Banco de Dados").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

            nApolBanco = Cells(nlin, "B")

            If UCase(nApolBanco) Like nApol Then
                MsgBox ("Found")
                ListBox1.ColumnCount = 14

                ListBox1.RowSource = Range(Cells(nlin, "A"), Cells(nlin, "T")).Address

            End If

        Next
    Else
        MsgBox ("Não encontrado")
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solução

Uma Range não contígua precisa ser criada com cada Range desejada e no fim preencher a ListBox com estes dados.
Pois com `ListBox.RowSource`, a listbox é preenchida com o intervalo desejado. Zerando toda vez que esta função é chamada.

E matrizes foram utilizadas para procurar pelo valor `nApol`, pois diminui a interação com a Planilha Excel e é mais rápido.

#### Código

```
Dim nApol As String
Dim nApolBanco As String
Dim nlin As Long
Dim Linha As Range
Dim ListaApol As Variant
Dim rng As Range, nova_range As Range
Dim BD As Worksheet
Set BD = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Banco de Dados")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Me.ListBox1.ColumnCount = 14
If Len(Me.TextBox1.Value) > 3 Then
    nApol = TextBox1.Value + TextBox2.Value + TextBox3.Value
    With BD
        ListaApol = .Range("B2:B" & .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value2
        For nlin = LBound(ListaApol) To UBound(ListaApol)
            nApolBanco = ListaApol(nlin, 1)
            If UCase(nApolBanco) Like nApol Then
                MsgBox ("Found")
                If rng Is Nothing Then
                    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(nlin + 1, "A"), .Cells(nlin + 1, "T"))
                Else
                    Set nova_rng = .Range(.Cells(nlin + 1, "A"), .Cells(nlin + 1, "T"))
                    Set rng = Union(rng, nova_rng)
                End If
            End If
        Next nlin
        Me.ListBox1.RowSource = rng.Address
    End With
Else
    MsgBox ("Não encontrado")
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

#### Passos

1. Cria a matriz ListaApol com os valores da coluna B
2. Realiza o loop do menor valor de índice de ListaApol (Lbound) até o maior valor (Ubound) com a variável `nlin`
3. Encontra os valores correspondentes
4. Se for a primeira vez que um valor é encontrado, ou seja, `rng` é Nothing, rng é igual ao intervalo desejado. Caso contrário, cria um intervalo não contíguo com todas as Ranges que possui o valor desejado
5. Preenche a ListBox com os valores do intervalo não contíguo `rng`

> A função `ListBox.AddItem` possui um limite de 10 colunas, como são utilizadas 14 colunas, a solução de intervalo não contíguo é a mais recomendada.

Answer (score 2):

Tenta dessa forma:

```
Private Sub Pesquisar_Click()
    Dim nApol As String
    Dim nApolBanco As String
    Dim nlin As Long
    Dim Linha As Range
    Dim arrayItems()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If Len(Me.TextBox1.Value) > 3 Then

        nApol = TextBox1.Value + TextBox2.Value + TextBox3.Value

        ListBox1.ColumnCount = Range("T:T").Column

        RowCount = Sheets("Banco de Dados").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        ReDim arrayItems(1 To RowCount, 1 To Range("T:T").Column)

        lin = 1

        For nlin = 2 To RowCount

            nApolBanco = Cells(nlin, "B")

            If UCase(nApolBanco) Like nApol Then

                ListBox1.AddItem
                For coluna = 1 To Range("T:T").Column
                    arrayItems(lin, coluna) = Cells(nlin, coluna).Value
                Next coluna
                lin = lin + 1

            End If
        Next

        ListBox1.List = arrayItems()

    Else
        MsgBox ("Não encontrado")
    End If

End Sub
```

Você cria um array com os dados e ao mesmo tempo vai adicionando linhas no ListBox com `ListBox1.AddItem` e depois adiciona os dados do array.